# Dhcpcd config file - two wifi configs at once

Tags: raspbian, networking, dhcp

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W v 1.1, to which I don't have any way to connect display adapter, therefore I communicate with it through ssh. It is connected to one isolated wifi network(with no internet access) for this connection. I need to connect it to another wifi at the same time from a different wifi adapter - connection is allowed only from certain Mac address, so I must use it - in order to have internet access. From the information I understood from here:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921

That on older raspbian versions connection was as easy as modifying the interfaces file with wpa-conf parameter. However, on new versions all things are resolved by dhcpcd.conf, where I can't find direct equivalent of this functionality. Is there any way to do this in this version, or should I just go back to old way of defining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different wpa_supplicant files for each interface.

If you search my Answer on setting up network  “Use different wpa_supplicant files “ explains.

> Create a file named `wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` e.g. `wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` will only be used by wlan0.

It is a good idea to enable *Predictable Network Interface Names* which will create an interface based on MAC, to ensure that only the desired interface is used.

Comment: I've read the answer in detail, seems like I didn't notice the "Use different wpa_supplicant files" section. It works flawlessly after following instructions. Thanks for your time :)